# How to encapsulate IIF and ISNULL call in Access 2010 VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, isnull, iif

I use the following expression pattern in my Access 2010 database frequently:

```
IIF(ISNULL(fieldName), Null, myFunction(fieldName))
```

Here myFunction is a user defined function that turns the value of fieldName into another format, if it does exists.

Just for a little bit reduce of typing, I tried to define the following function:

```
Function IifIsNull(p AS Variant, v AS Variant) AS Variant
    If IsNull(p) Then IifIsNull = p Else IifIsNull = v
End Function
```

and I supposed to use it in the following way:

```
IifIsNull(fieldName, myFunction(fieldName))
```

But it does not work. When `fieldName` is Null, the return value of the `IifIsNull` is `#Error`, and `IifIsNull` has even not been called!

Is it possible to simplify the given code pattern with a user defined function or system function at all?

UPDATE:

There are a couple of `myFunction`s, and all of those functions are currently strongly typed, a simple example is the following:

```
Function RemoveSpace(str AS String) AS String
    For i=1 to Len(str)
        If Mid(str,i,1) <> " " Then RemoveSpace = RemoveSpace + Mid(str,i,1)
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `myFunction(fieldName)` throws an error when `fieldName` is null.

When you call `IifIsNull(fieldName, myFunction(fieldName))`, the first thing that gets evaluated is `myFunction(fieldName)`. So if `fieldName` is null, you get an error.

Comment: You are indicating the reason of the `#Error`, and my question is not about the reason, but solution.

Comment: I think a wise man once said something like: understand the reason, then seek a solution. Or was it a fortune cookie... Anyhow, it makes sense, doesn't it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply evaluate fieldname in MyFunction?

Append an empty string to field name to ensure it always passes a string, not a null.

```
=MyFunction(FieldName & "")

Function MyFunction(Fieldname) As Variant
   ''Depending on what your function does, it is may not necessary to check
   If FieldName<>"" Then
       MyFunction = FieldName & " was here"
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: The point here is that `MyFunction` is strongly typed, say `Function MyFunction(fildName AS String) As String`. And also there are a couple of those functions, so it will be hard to change all of them.

Comment: In that case, pass a string. I will add a note.